# startup-script doesn't run on first boot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The `startup-script` added to an instance in GCP doesn't seem to run on first boot (but does on subsequent boots)

I'm using the `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-7-v20160921` base image but had the same issue on a slightly older version of the centos-7 image too.

This happens whether I use the API to create an instance, or the web console.

According to the docs (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) adding a metadata with the key `startup-script` and value of a script should cause the script to be run on *every* boot.

(There is a section about adding the script to a running instance, and it mentions that a reboot is required to get the script to run, but this (apparently) shouldn't apply to new instances.)

It's possible to force the script to run using `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup` (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript) which implies that the script is loaded, but just not run, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a bug in GCP? :)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same behavior on my test account. I would suggest filing a new issue on the public Issue tracker [1] which then will be redirected to Google's engneering team in order to fix it as soon as possible. [1] https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list

Comment: Thanks, I've opened the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=433

Comment: This issue went away by itself, so either google quietly fixed the issue with their image or I was doing something wrong from the start. In any case, I'm no longer able to reproduce it.

Comment: I just ran into this as well. It still seems to be an issue. My google customer account can't seem to view that issue. I've opened a support case with google, but they are suggesting an instance level script, which is a no go for us. We are using a mix of *nix and win environments so the solutions below won't work for us.

Answer (score 1):

This actually worked for me without issues using the Centos 7 image. I created the VM from the console and added this small script

```
#! /bin/bash
yum update
yum install -y httpd
cat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html
<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>This page was created from a simple startup script!</p>
</body></html>
EOF
```

After the VM was created I was able to verify that Apache had been installed in the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

```
…
Feb  3 20:36:17 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: ---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-45.el7.centos will be installed
Feb  3 20:36:17 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: --> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-45.el7.centos for package: httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.x86_64
Feb  3 20:36:17 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: --> Processing Dependency: /etc/mime.types for package: httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.x86_64
….
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: Installed:
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script:   httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-45.el7.centos
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: Dependency Installed:
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script:   apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7                     apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script:   httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-45.el7.centos     mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.41-2.el7
Feb  3 20:36:20 instance-3 startup-script: INFO startup-script: Complete!
```

The script did install Apache but the service in the VM was not started. I just had to SSH in the VM to start the service.

Comment: That's normal behaviour for RHEL-based distros, my startup script also includes the lines `systemctl enable httpd` `systemctl start httpd`

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Looking at the serial console might provide some hints.

Comment: I stopped being able to reproduce the problem. Not sure exactly why and I wasn't keeping particularly good notes when it was occurring. It may have been down to incorrect network setup in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it still exists and it is tricky.

Startup scripts are ran after all `init.d` scripts.

So if you initialise a `/etc/environment` file for example and try to use it in a `init.d` script, on the first boot, `/etc/environment` will not exist when your script will be launched.

On the second boot, there is no more problem, `/etc/environment` already exists :-)